# How to create multi-dimensional array typedef in Python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, typedef

In C++, one can create a typedef for 1D, 2D arrays and then use them to declare variables.

```cpp
typedef char my2DDataArr[2][2];
typedef int my1DDataArr[10];

my2DDataArr arr2d_1= {{0,1},{2,3}};
my1DDataArr arr1d_1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

How can I accomplish similar in Python ?

Comment: You don't need to declare variable types in Python at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is strongly but dynamically typed. That means that you don't need to let the compiler know what type a variable will be - mostly because python code isn't compiled.

So obviously you could simply do something like:

```py
my_list = [] # List that can contain other lists, could be 1D or nD        
initialized_list = [[1, 2], [2, 4]]
```

Now as I wrote the list *can* contain other lists. Some people don't like the uncertainty and lack of readability when you don't define the type of the variable. For that you do have two different solutions:

```py
import numpy as np
my_array = np.ndarray((2, 2)) # 2D Array
initialized_array = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4]])
```

Now that notation should look more familiar to you, as that is a 2 dimensional array. Unlike a list it can and will have only 2 dimensions, 4 elements total (2x2). If you don't care about the array being immutable and/or want mutability you  can just use *type-hints*:

```py
from typing import List
my_list: List[List[int]]
my_list = []
```

Writing it like this says that it's a list that will contain lists of integers. Size is still not limited but a smart IDE will give you warnings if you start putting something else into it or if you make it 3 dimensional.

Comment: Probably worth noting that type hints are just that - hints for IDEs, and not enforced by the interpreter

Answer (score 1):

The Python equivalent would be

```
arr2d_1 = [[0,1],[2,3]]
arr1d_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

There's no *typedef* and no need to specify a variable's type. At most you could do:

```
arr2d_1:list = [[0,1],[2,3]]
arr1d_1:list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

But even then, the `:list` part is called a [type *hint*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which will help some IDEs in refactoring, it's not a strict requirement for the interpreter.